# web middleware for specific routes in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, middleware, laravel-middleware

In Laravel 5.4 the web middleware is included on all routes by default. But I want to show those routes(menu's) assign to users. For example 
I have some routes(menu's) as follows

```
user\list
user\add
user\show_form
list\forms
```

if user 'ABC' assign only two routes(menu's) like

```
`user\list`
`user\add`
```

so when user 'ABC' is logged that in menu shows only two routes(menu's) those assign. When user create that time I assign routes(menu's) and this stored in permission table. Now my question is how can I handle this using middleware. 
Is this possible handle via middleware. please suggest me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pulling from the database, what I would do is skip the middleware idea all together and approach this by querying the user's routes and then displaying them on the page. I would accomplish this by using a service provider.

Let's assume you have your project set up with a `user-navigation.blade.php` file which contains your user's nav elements. Maybe something like:

```
<ul class="side-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/user/list">List</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/user/add">Add</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you are bringing that file into your other blade template with `@include('user-navigation')`.

What we want to do is do a query for the current user's routes ANY time that view (user-navigation) is displayed to the user. We can do this easily with a service provider.

Run the following command in your terminal: `php artisan make:provider UserNavigationServiceProvider`. Next, we need to tell Laravel to actually use this service provider. Open `config/app.php` and scroll down to the area where it says 'Application Service Providers' and add this: `App\Providers\UserNavigationServiceProvider::class,`. Now edit the file found in `app\Providers\UserNavigationServiceProvider.php`

If you're using Laravel's default Authentication, bring it in at the top of your file: `use Auth;`. We also need to bring in the model for your `permissions` table. So put `use App\Permission;` at the top of this file as well.

Now, in the `boot()` method, make it look like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->getUserNavigation();
}
```

Next, we're going to create the `getUserNavigation()` method. Just below the `register()` method, add this:

```
private function getUserNavigation()
{
    view()->composer('user-navigation', function($view)
    {
        $userID = Auth::id();

        $userNavigation = ! is_null($userID) ? Provider::where('user_id', $userID)->get() : null;

        $view->with([ 'userNavigation' => $userNavigation ]);
    });
}
```

So lets break down what we're doing in this new method. First, we're saying we want to target the view by the name of `user-navigation`. Any time this view is loaded we're going to perform the logic in this closure. Next, we use the default Laravel Auth way to obtain the current user's ID, then we run a query on the `permissions` table using Eloquent. **NOTE:** I am assuming you have a column in your `permissions` table that is `user_id`. This query gives us a collection of all the records owned by that user in the `permissions` table. Now we're binding that result to the variable `$userNavigation` and passing it to `user-navigation` as `$userNavigation`. **NOTE:** Because you are including `user-navigation.blade.php` in another file, that file will also have access to this `$userNavigation` variable.

Now, in `user-navigation.blade.php` lets write the logic. First we check to see if that variable is `null`. You can optionally skip this if you know a non-logged in user will **never** access this view. Then simply loop through it and display the results.

```
@if ( $userNavigation )
<ul class="side-nav">
    @foreach( $userNavigation as $navItem )
    <li>
        <a href="{{ $navItem->url }}">{{ $navItem->url_name }}</a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

In the above example I am *assuming* you have a database column called `url` where you are storing the link and a column called `url_name` where you are storing the text for the anchor link. If not, you might consider adding those.

And that's it. You can use a service provider to give your view file(s) access to certain data any time they are used.

Hope this helps.